# Getting org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found everyime

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a dotnet based web service on a different server. I am trying to communicate using java. The webservice is working fine. If I use the envelope created by Axis2 inside the stub, in soapUI, I get the response.  In the stub class, error is thrown when

> _operationClient.execute(true);

is executed. In servlet, I have the following code

```
WebServiceStub wss = WebServiceStub();
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
//set all values in mc
wss.method(mc);
```

I also tried

```
wss._getServiceClient().getOptions().getProperties().put("dotNetSoapEncFix", "true");
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: Try whith this. It may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4456342/840635