# While i am trying to call my web service it is giving the following exception, on the other hand if i try to open service Url its working fine

Tags: java, web-services

I have a web service which is used to read the data from crystal report. but while i am trying to execute it , its showing "404 not found". I have tried to open web service URL in browser and its opening up there, that means my web service URl is ok. So what can be the reason for this error. Its giving the following error

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:296)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:190)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:448)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:401)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
    at com.citigroup.cai.crservice.ws.CRServiceStub.GenerateCrystalReportWithOptionsAndParameters(CRServiceStub.java:243)
    at com.citigroup.cai.lpp.common.crystal.CRServiceClient.executeCrystalReport(CRServiceClient.java:338)
    at com.citigroup.cai.lpp.ods.obf.csam.CsamReportProcessor.executeCrystalReport(CsamReportProcessor.java:715)
    at com.citigroup.cai.lpp.ods.obf.csam.CsamReportProcessor.processReport(CsamReportProcessor.java:420)
    at com.citigroup.cai.lpp.ods.obf.csam.CsamReportProcessor.processReports(CsamReportProcessor.java:333)
    at com.citigroup.cai.lpp.ods.obf.csam.CsamReportProcessor.process(CsamReportProcessor.java:224)
    at com.citigroup.cai.lpp.ods.obf.csam.CsamReportProcessor.main(CsamReportProcessor.java:1007)
```

Comment: Did you copy the full URI and pasted it onto your browser? You can check the parameters, since any HTTP error can be thrown from within the application, even if the URI is there. Anyways, give us more details, since the stack trace is not much of use in this case.

Comment: This is already being discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456342/axis2-always-getting-404-errors